# Is it possible to change ostringstream rdbuf?

Tags: c++, streambuf, ostringstream

I try the following code:

```
ostringstream oss;

streambuf *psbuf, *backup;

backup = oss.rdbuf();     
psbuf = cout.rdbuf();        
oss.rdbuf(psbuf);        
oss << things << endl;
oss.rdbuf(backup);
```

But unfortunately I get this error:

```
error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1
    oss.rdbuf(backup);
```

But rdbuf has two overloads:

> get (1) basic_streambuf<char_type,traits_type>* rdbuf() const;
>
> set (2) basic_streambuf<char_type,traits_type>* rdbuf (basic_streambuf<char_type,traits_type>* sb);

Yes I know it says `basic_streambuf` but it really is just a typedef `typedef basic_streambuf<char> streambuf;`, so it should work. Why is it not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though `std::ostringstream` inherits `rdbuf` from `std::basic_ios` that overload will not be accessible due to the fact that `std::basic_ostream` also defines its own member-function named `rdbuf`, effectively hiding the overload(s) you are looking for.

You can get access to the member-function by casting your `std::ostringstream` instance to a `std::ostream` reference as in the below example:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
std::ostream&      oss_ref = oss;

auto prev = oss_ref.rdbuf (std::cout.rdbuf ());

oss << "hello world"; // will print to the buffer of std::cout

oss_ref.rdbuf (prev); // reset
```

```
static_cast<std::ostream&> (oss).rdbuf (...) // equivalent
```

---

**Why does `std::basic_ostringstream` define its own `rdbuf`?**

Normally `rdbuf` returns a `std::basic_streambuf*` but `std::ostringstream` uses a `std::basic_stringbuf`.

Since one cannot overload based on return-type a decision was made to effectively hide the former overload in favour of the new one.

By returning a `std::basic_stringbuf` it's easy to see that `std::ostringstream` uses a *stringbuf* internally, and it also provides easier access to the `str` functions of `std::basic_stringbuf` (functions which doesn't exist in `std::basic_streambuf`).

Comment: Why doesn't `basic_ostringstream` also define another `rdbuf(basic_stringbuf*)`?

Answer (score 0):

Because in the class `ostringstream` (typedef of `basic_ostringstream<char>`), only the gettor version of `rdbuf()` was defined as its member function, so the settor version inheriting from base class was **hided**. You can use the settor version of `rdbuf()` by upcasting `oss` to the base class such as `ostream`.

Comment: I'm also puzzled by why `ostringstream` was designed by this way?